# Need select 2 rows from Table2, which is joined with Table1. See description

Tags: sql-server

For example i have a Table1:

```
ID Specified TIN Value DateCreated
----------------------------------
1       0   tin1   45   2014-12-30
2       1   tin2   34   2013-01-05
3       0   tin3   23   2015-02-20
4       3   tin4   47   2013-06-04
5       3   tin5   12   2012-04-02
```

And a Table2:

```
ID Table1ID RegistrationDate
----------------------------------
1       1      2015-10-12
2       2      2015-07-21
3       1      2015-11-26
4       1      2015-12-04
5       2      2015-09-18
```

I need select all columns from Table1 with first and last RegistrationDate column in Table2. The answer should be

```
ID Specified TIN Value DateCreated   FirstRegDate   LastRegDate
---------------------------------------------------------------
1       0   tin1   45   2014-12-30    2015-10-12    2015-12-04
2       1   tin2   34   2013-01-05    2015-07-21    2015-09-18
3       0   tin3   23   2015-02-20    NULL          NULL
4       3   tin4   47   2013-06-04    NULL          NULL
5       3   tin5   12   2012-04-02    NULL          NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi one possible solution can be something similar to pseudo query below(if you can prepare the tables I will modify to reflect actual query)

```
SELECT table1.*, inlineTable2.firstRegDate, inlineTable2.lastRegDate 
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT
   Table1ID AS id,
   MIN(registrationDate) as firstRegDate,
   MAX(regsitrationDate) as lastRegDate
   FROM table2
   GROUP BY table1ID
) AS inlineTable2
ON table1.id = inlineTable2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `group by` all columns in table1, and look up the minumum and maximum registration date for the group:

```
select  ID
,       Specified
,       ... other columns from table1 ...
,       min(RegistrationDate)
,       max(RegistrationDate)
from    Table1 t1
left join
        Table2 t2
on      t1.ID = t2.Table1ID
group by
        ID
,       Specified
,       ... other columns from table1 ...
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working). I will accept this answer as soon as i achieve 15 reputation!